# Titanium: Text decided to not show up today on android

Tags: android, android-ndk, titanium, appcelerator

So I have been developing an app for android and iOS for quite a while. Today was supposed to be the submission day! I have been doing all my android testing on a Samsung Galaxy S4 with Android 4.4.2.

I have been using `Ti SDK 3.2.1` during this whole process. I've noticed there has been an update wanting to update titanium the past week or two but I have been ignoring it until I get this release out.

So today I am doing my final tests and my login screen now shows no text. I can type in the inputs and work all my buttons, just no text is visible.

The console is also throwing some new errors that just started showing today:

```
[WARN] :   linker: libstlport_shared.so has text relocations. This is wasting memory and is a security risk. Please fix.
[WARN] :   linker: libkroll-v8.so has text relocations. This is wasting memory and is a security risk. Please fix.
[WARN] :   linker: libtiverify.so has text relocations. This is wasting memory and is a security risk. Please fix.
[WARN] :   ApplicationPackageManager: getCSCPackageItemText()
[WARN] :   V8Object: Runtime disposed, cannot set property 'userAgent'
[ERROR] :  ViewSystem: ViewRootImpl #2 Surface is not valid.
```

Those weird "linker" errors. This just started showing today. So I try and remedy the problem by updating to that new `Ti SDK 3.2.2`. I get through that, update all the android SDKs, update the android NDK and still, same thing.

I've cleaned the project, removed it entirely from the phone, rebooted the phone, my computer and so on.

I can however see the text on an older android device that I have. It is n `samsung galaxy stellar` and when I compile I do not get those errors.

Can anyone think of what is going on here and WHY it just started happening today after no SDK updates?

I can type in the two fields no problem. I cant see any of the text. Also, the text on my button magically disappeared.

[image: yay android...]

**EDIT 2**
I am thinking this has something to do with the screen density setting in `tiapp.xml`

if I change:

```
<android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <manifest>
        <uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="11"/>
        <supports-screens android:anyDensity="false"
            android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true"
            android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true"/>
    </manifest>
</android>
```

to this:

```
<android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <manifest>
        <uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="11"/>
        <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true"
            android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true"
            android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true"/>
    </manifest>
</android>
```

my text reappears. Other elements on the screen now appear smaller though..yay android...

Comment: Having the same problem now, I feel your pain!

Comment: Any solutions? Facing the issue and this is really annoying.

Comment: If I remember correctly, it had to do with setting padding on the text field. I think I had a padding set on it and I had to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post some of your code for the text fields? Can't help you troubleshoot with just the error messages and tiapp.xml.

Also, I would try deleting the build folder in your workspace. Then for good measure just do a 'Project'->'Clean' command and run again.

Comment: It had to do with the `anyDensity` property. I had to change it to `true` and adjust all my other elements on screen